# Build JSON object using database relations/foreign key PHP

Tags: php, json, database, orm, foreign-key-relationship

I need some help.

What I need to do basically, it's a simple mapping relation (FK) between to databases and bring this as JSON (using php).

For example, I have those two abstract databases:

1: Costumer

```
+-------+-----------+----------+
|  id   |    name   |  car_id  |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

2: Car

```
+-------+-----------+----------+
|  id   |    model  |  price   |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

And I need a JSON like:

```
{
    "customers": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "First Customer",
        "car": {
            "id": "1",
            "model": "sampleCar",
            "price:": "19.33"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "second Customer",
        "car": {
            "id": "2",
            "model": "betterCar",
            "price:": "99.33"
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm using MySQL to save this data, but I *can* change the database - The only thing I *can't* change is the PHP.

My question is: 
There is a performative way to do this *without* using frameworks?
(Or maybe a framework who do just it?)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you can't change the PHP? What PHP do you already have? The PHP has to create the appropriate query for the data.

Comment: What happens if a customer has more than one car? You should use a many-to-many table to link customers with cars. Or if a car can only have one owner, you should put `owner_id` in `car`.

Comment: @Barmar, I mean that the back-end language must be PHP, I can change the code, though. :) 
The real objects are one-to-one, I used customer and cars just to exemplify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple `JOIN` query, and then the fetching loop creates the appropriate data.

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id AS cus_id, c.name, car.id AS car_id, car.model, car.price
        FROM customer AS c
        LEFT JOIN car ON car.id = c.car_id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$customers = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch) {
    if ($row['car_id'] != null) {
        $car = array('id' => $row['car_id'],
                     'model' => $row['model'],
                     'price' => $row['price']);
    } else {
        $car = null;
    }
    $customers[] = array('id' => $row['cus_id'],
                         'name' => $row['name'],
                         'car' => $car);
}

$result = array('customers' => $customers);
```

Comment: Thanks!
There aren't a more dynamic way to do this?

Comment: There are probably some frameworks that automate it, although I'm not sure they would be able to create the nesting that you want for `car`, since the query returns everything on the same row. If it were a 1-to-many relationship between customers and cars they could probably create an array of cars automatically.